# Disabling TaxYear end for 18-19

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently my screen is displaying this as shown below while selecting the tax year code.

[image: Having tax year 2018-2019]

I wish to disable the tax year as from 2018-2019 that is on the dropbox while selecting the tax year, 2018-2019 should not be there.

Below is the stored procedure which loads tax years on the screen.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TYEEYUSubmission_GetTaxYears] (
  @PayrollNumber VARCHAR(10)
) AS BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4)) AS TaxYear
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4)) + ' / ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4) - 1) AS TaxYearDesc
  FROM RSTPayrollPeriod
  WHERE PayrollNumber = @PayrollNumber
    -- AND PeriodRunType = 'E'  
  ORDER BY TaxYear DESC
END
```

Could you please advise how to amend the stored procedure so as the tax year '2018-2019' does not appear on the drop box?

I'm new on SQL that is why it's a bit difficult to understand this. Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: ... `WHERE PayrollNumber = @PayrollNumber AND TaxYearDesc <> '2018 / 2019'`

Comment: In the code year / (year-1) is selected but in your output we see the opposite, (year-1) / year. Why is that? Also can you explain what data type `PayrunPeriod` is, I have assumed text and/or post some sample data from the `RSTPayrollPeriod` table?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using SQL Server so this is my solution. I am assuming `PayrunPeriod` is a date stored as a string

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TYEEYUSubmission_GetTaxYears] (
  @PayrollNumber VARCHAR(10)
) AS BEGIN
  DECLARE @year int;
  SET @year = DATEPART( yyyy, GETDATE());

  SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4)) AS TaxYear
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4)) + ' / ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), LEFT(PayrunPeriod, 4) - 1) AS TaxYearDesc
  FROM RSTPayrollPeriod
  WHERE PayrollNumber = @PayrollNumber
    AND CONVERT(INT, LEFT(PayrunPeriod,4)) < @year
  ORDER BY TaxYear DESC
END
```

Comment: @S.John This answer is correct for the procedure given in the question but I suspect that procedure is not the one used for the output given in the question.